# Posting Image to Pinterest API

Tags: multipartform-data, pinterest, data-url

I am trying to post a image to Pinterest using their SDK (PDK). The specific method I am using is

> PDK.request('/pins/',
>         'POST',
>         {
>            board: board.id,
>            note: "description",
>            link: "link",
>            image_base64: ""
>                },
>          function(e){
>            console.log(e);
>          });

There are three options to send the image.

1. sending the image_url in the options object.
2. sending the image_base64 (data url) which is what is shown in my code
3. using a multipart form data

[Pinterest docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/)

I can only use options 2 and 3. For options 2 it works for small images until the dataURL gets too big. Pinterest API does not have any helpful errors when this occurs and this is only my speculation.

The alternative is to use a multipart form data but I am not sure how to do that.

Can someone help me posting using the multipart form data for image posting?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as well and got a bit stuck. I've tried creating a `new FormData` object and POSTing it with XMLHttpRequest with the token in the header. I ended up with an error saying `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: do you mind giving me a code snippet of your params especially where you would add the auth token? I am currently using PDK, are you using a hand made request?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work because of the error I mentioned above but here's a gist of what my code looks like.

`let form = new FormData();`
`form.append('board', board.id);`
`// ... the rest of the fields I need`
`form.append('image', my_image);`

`let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();`
`ajax.onload = handlePintRes;`
`ajax.open('POST', 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=' + token);`
`ajax.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BEARER ' + token );`
`ajax.send(form);`

Comment: Could you tell me what the my_image is. Is it a base64 data_url?

Comment: I tried uploading an image file. I've also tried replacing that field with image_base64, adding all parameters into the url instead of the form (aside from the image file), as well as repeating the information in both the url and form.

Answer (score 3):

I also couldn't make their SDK work, but I've sorted this out, at least for dataurl:

```
var sendForm = new FormData();
sendForm.append('board', pathname);
sendForm.append('note', label);
sendForm.append('link', linkURL);
sendForm.append('image_base64', dataUrl);

var url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=" + window.pinterestAccessToken;

$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: sendForm,
   processData: false, //this is very important for making sure the formdata object is sent in the correct format
   contentType: false,
   type: 'POST'
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me as well. When I tried via their base64 solution I got cross-origin error and a string to long error